# Vector bundle over projective space

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-bundles, topological-vector-spaces, fiber-bundles, topological-k-theory

The following exercise is from Atiyah's book "K-theory", Example 2.

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $\mathbb{P}(V)$ be its associated projective space. That is $\mathbb{P}(V)=\frac{V\backslash\{0\}}{\sim}$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation given by $v_1\sim v_2$ iff $\mathbb{C}v_1=\mathbb{C}v_2$. 
We define $E\subseteq \mathbb{P}(V)\times V$ to be the set of all $(x,v)$ such that $v$ lies in the line determining $x$.
Show that $E$ is a vector bundle over $\mathbb{P}(V)$, with the canonical projection map $E\to \mathbb{P}(V)$ maps $(x,v)$ to $x$.

My question: First of all, I don't understand why $x$ determines a line, I mean- the equivalence calss $x=[v_1]$, seems to be a sphere, and not a line...because we consider complex scalars.

Secondly, I could not show that it is locally trivial. Given some $x=[v_1]$ in $\mathbb{P}(V)$, I need to find some open subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{P}(V)$ containing $x$, such that $E|_{U}$ is isomorphic to $U\times W$, for some vector space $W$. I have no idea how to do so... I noticed that the fivers are one-dimensional, for $x=[v_1]$, $E_x$ is isomorphic to the subspace spanned by $v_1$.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It is a complex line, a $1$-dimensional complex vector space.

Comment: I think your fail is in the projective space definiton. Usually, $~ $ is define as an equivalence relation such that if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are related, then there is a $\lambda$ satisfying $v_1=\lambda v_2$, i. e. both $v_1$ and $v_2$ are related iff they lie in the same line. So that $[v_1]$ is precisely that line.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I understand now, Thank you.

Comment: You may want to prove the statement for a real vector space first.  Then think about changes (if any) you need to make to your argument.

Comment: @Dog_69, that relation and the one in the question are exactly the same one.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, Yes but I think with my definition (it isn't mine, you know) is clearer they are in the same line.

Comment: @Dog_69, the line that contains a nonzero vector $v$ is precisely the set $\mathbb Cv$, so there is no more clear version of "the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are on the same line" than «$\mathbb Cv_1=\mathbb Cv_2$»!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: I have to disagree. "Clarity" is psychological rather than mathematical, and what's clearest to you may be most opaque to me. I happen to like your choice and Dog_69's as well, but each has made more sense to me than the other at different times in my mathematical education.

Comment: Indeed. It is possible that there are more clear ways of writing the condition that  a line L and a line L' are equal other than «$L=L'$» :-)

Comment: @Kiko, as for the last part of your question: I suggest you try to see how that vector bundle looks on one of the standard open sets of projective space.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Let me try to explain how I see it in the case of the real projective line $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$. I want to identify it as points on the sphere $S^2$ , where every point is identifies with its antipodal. Then, for an equivalence class, I can take a small open neighborhood U of the point and its antipodal (symmetrically) on the sphere, viewed as two small open disks. So, it seems like it is going to be isomorphic to $U\times \mathbb{R}^2$, this is just intuition in the real case and small dimension. Is it at least the right idea?

Comment: Using the sphere in the complex  case is not going to be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}$Let us assume that $V=\CC^{n+1}$. If $v\in V\setminus0$, let us write $[v]$ its class in $P(V)$.

The set
$$U=\{[(v_0,\dots,v_n)]\in P(V):v_0\neq0\}$$ is an open set, and the map $\phi:\CC^n\to U$ such that $$\phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)=[(1,x_1,\dots,x_n)]$$ for all $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\CC^n$ is a homeomorphism.

Now let $E=P(V)\times V$ be the subset of al pairs $(p,v)$ of $P(V)\times V$ such that $v\in p$, and let $\pi:E\to P(V)$ be the restriction to $E$ of the map $(p,v)\in P(V)\times V\mapsto p\in P(V)$.

Let, on the other hand, $p:\CC^n\times\CC^n$ be the projection on the first factor, and let $\Phi:\CC^n\times\CC\to E$ be the map such that $$\Phi(x,\lambda)=(\phi(x),\lambda x'),$$
where if $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ I am writing $x'=(1,x_1,\dots,x_n)$. The diagram
\begin{CD}
\CC^n\times\CC @>\Phi>> E \\
@VpVV @V\pi VV \\
\CC^n @>\phi>> P(V) 
\end{CD}

Now you have to check that this provides a trivialization of $E$ over the open set $U$, and use similar ideas to construct trivializations over all open sets of an open covering of $P(V)$.

Comment: Thank you! this is very helpful